# Integrating Quickblox with Temasys plugin for IE and Safari support

Tags: webrtc, quickblox, videochat

I am currently using Quickblox video platform for one-to-one video chat.

Quickblox only supports Chrome and Firefox browsers; [Skylink](http://skylink.io/) provides a [WebRTC plugin](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins) to support IE and Safari too.

Can we use the Skylink plugin with Quickblox API?

Here's what I've already done.

Gone through this link,

[https:// temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/How+to+integrate+the+Temasys+WebRTC+Plugin+into+your+website](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/How+to+integrate+the+Temasys+WebRTC+Plugin+into+your+website)

But as I add the below script tag,

```
<script src="https://cdn.temasys.com.sg/adapterjs/0.11.x/adapter.debug.js"></script>
```

Quickblox stop working with this error

```
quickblox.js:2250 Uncaught TypeError: peer.init is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: peer.init is not a functionWebRTCProxy._createPeer @ quickblox.js:2250WebRTCProxy.call @ quickblox.js:2259(anonymous function) @ student.js:244(anonymous function) @ quickblox.js:2156
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not familiar with Quickblox, I would expect that they have their own way of shimming the differences between browsers (their own adapter.js if you will).

Simply including AJS on your page might mess up their code.
You would probably have to modify their code a little bit with the guidance from [the integration guide you pointed to](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/How+to+integrate+the+Temasys+WebRTC+Plugin+into+your+website).

We did the same with PeerJS a while ago and it worked fine. 
Alternatively you could try integrating SkylinkJS :)

Comment: Ended up using Skylinks only. With the changing SDK and number of changes to be made we felt we could use the SDK itself.